# Nautilus set working directory

Tags: gnome3, nautilus

I have it so that when I double click a jar it'll mimeopen the jar with java. The problem is that for whatever reason nautilus uses my home directory as the current working directory so the jar can't find any of it's resources and I end up having to launch it from bash. Is there any way I can make it so that nautilus uses the current directory as the working directory for mimeopen?

Comment: Known [bug in `nautilus`](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=535277) see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4157358

Comment: @don_crissti good lord this bug report is from 2008 and it's still present. I get the feeling this'll never be fixed.

Comment: yeah man, I know... this is typical for `nautilus`... there are other things (even more annoying) that haven't been fixed yet and the bug reports [date back from 2004](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=138931)

Comment: @don_crissti wow that's really dumb...hopefully this gets fixed because ummm it's really annoying but I guess bash FTW for now. Unfortunately that's kinda a not great solution.